# C: Address of (c)allocated array does not fit with size of data type (I think....)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, calloc

The following code is supposed to allocate some memory for a 2D array. I print their values and addresses to the screen but am confused about the output...

This is the C-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_2Darr( double **arr_2D, int N_rows, int N_cols );

int main(){

    int ii;

    const int N_cols = 4;
    const int N_rows = 3;

    double
        **arr;

    // note: for readibility, checking for NULL is omitted
    // allocate pointer to rows, then rows...
    arr    = calloc( (size_t)N_rows, sizeof *arr );
    arr[0] = calloc( (size_t)(N_rows*N_cols), sizeof **arr );
    // ... and set pointers to them
    for ( ii=1 ; ii<N_rows ; ++ii ) 
        arr[ii] = arr[ii-1] + N_cols;

    // print values their address of them
    print_2Darr( arr, N_rows, N_cols );

    // not to be forgotten...
    free( arr[0] );
    free( arr );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void print_2Darr( double **arr_2D, int N_rows, int N_cols ) {
    int
        ii, jj;

    for ( ii=0 ; ii<N_rows ; ++ii) {
        for ( jj=0 ; jj<N_cols; ++jj)
            printf( "%f (%p)\t", arr_2D[ii][jj], (void*)&arr_2D[ii][jj] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Now comes the crucial part, the output might look like this:

```
0.000000 (0x12dc030)    0.000000 (0x12dc038)    0.000000 (0x12dc040)    0.000000 (0x12dc048)
0.000000 (0x12dc050)    0.000000 (0x12dc058)    0.000000 (0x12dc060)    0.000000 (0x12dc068)
0.000000 (0x12dc070)    0.000000 (0x12dc078)    0.000000 (0x12dc080)    0.000000 (0x12dc088)
```

I would have expected that the address would be higher by 8 byte walking through the array. Apparently, this is only true for every second step (from the 0th element to the 1st, then from the 2nd to the 3rd etc.). The address is advances by 8 byte, then 2 byte, then 8 byte, then 2 byte and so on.

What am I doing wrong, is it how I print the address?

Comment: The cast to `size_t` is redundant, since C has implicit conversion between integer types.

Comment: Not your actual question, but since C99 you can use a single `malloc` with array syntax, instead of setting up this table of syntactic-sugar-providing row pointers

Comment: @M.M hmm.... you mean something like `(*arr)[N_cols] = calloc(N_rows * N_cols, sizeof **arr )` ?

Comment: Yes something like that

Comment: this line: `arr[0] = calloc( (size_t)(N_rows*N_cols), sizeof **arr );` needs to be a loop, calling `calloc()` once for each row, similar to this: `for( int i=0;i<N_rows; i++ ) { arr[i] = calloc( N_cols, sizeof( double ) ); }   Then the pointers are already set and the correct amounts of allocated memory gotten.  Then the row pointers need to be passed to `free()` in a loop

Comment: but this requires (N_rows-1) more `calloc` calls and might therefore be more resource-demanding (?). But it is more readable and might therefore be more attractive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The addresses ARE incrementing by 8 bytes. They are in *hex*.

```
0x12dc030
0x12dc038 - difference of 8 from the above
0x12dc040 - difference of 8 from the above
```